# Integral when function is unknown?

Tags: python, math, python-2.7, integral

I'm trying to find a way to calculate area under a curve using python 2.7 when the function is unknown. Only data I have are coordinates, such as:

```
0       0
0.000194439     0
0.000388878     0
0.000583317     0
0.000777756     0
0.000972195     0
0.00116663      0
0.00136107      0
0.00155551      0
0.00174995      0
0.00194439      0
0.00213883      0
0.00233327      0
0.00233327      0.00588235
0.00252771      0.00588235 
...............................
.................................
```

[Complete data](http://pastebin.com/b9jFrd9f).

The values will always be positive. 
More often than not the function will resemble a logarithmic one, but that is not guaranteed.

I could calculate (x2-x1)*y and so on for an approximation, but I'd prefer using integration.

Thus my question is:
How could I find out the function for given coordinates reliably in code? Or is it possible to accomplish this without one? Asking the latter merely to cover all bases, since my math is extremely rusty

Comment: Use least-squares(or an other method) to find a function that closely match the data set and compute its integral.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Not really a good idea. Finding that function will often be terribly tricky that will give a better approximation than a simple trapezoidal or simpson's rule. And you have now added another step to the problem, suggesting that someone with already problematic math skills now learn an entire set of new skills. Far better is a simple trapezoidal or simpson rule, or integrating a spline interpolant, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I find out the function for given coordinates reliably in code?

You can't.  Given a set of points, there are an infinite number of functions that go through all of those points.  One of them can be constructed using a [polynomial of degree up to N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) (where N is the number of data points that you have).  However, this is function almost never matches the reality you're trying to represent (It usually ends up oscillating wildly between data points).  In general, the best you can do is is to create some sort of approximation of the integral.

The approximation you've described isn't too bad on most functions as long as your sampling rate is adequate, although you could do a little better using the [trapeziodal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) or [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule).

Comment: "However, this is function almost never matches the reality you're trying to represent" - the point of interpolation is to perfectly go through all the points. The function will wildly oscillate outside the points (before the first one and after the last one), but will smoothly go through each point exactly.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would one implement the Simpson's rule without knowing the function?

Comment: @Bohren -- See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Alternative_extended_Simpson.27s_rule) for example.

Comment: @Tim The function can also wildly oscillate between the points.  If you fit a quadratic to 100e^{-x} at 0, 1, and 2, it looks fine between 0 and 2.  But if you fit a quadratic to 100e^{-4x} at 0, 1, and 2, the vertex for the parabola is now around (2.5,-11.1).  A more contrived but drastic example related to this is to look at a quadratic going through (0,1), (c,0), and (1,0) as c becomes small.  You find y=(x-c)(x-1)/c, which has its vertex at ((c+1)/2,-(1-c)^2/4c), which is going toward (1/2,-infinity).